# The Quantity field increments in decimals instead of whole numbers

Tags: commerce

Default installation of Commerce 2.x. The qty field for a product, when you click the up arrow to increase the quantity it goes from 1 to 1.01. I want it to go from 1 to 2 to 3, etc.

Comment: Which Drupal version do you use?

Comment: Please check what is the widget type in `/admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/default/edit/form-display` - there is an option to allow or disallow the decimal values for quantity. It should be of type 'Quantity' and 'Allow decimal quantities' checkbox should be unchecked. Beware though because this would be applied to all items from the given type and it might not be what you need.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 9.5.9 and Commerce 8.x-2.36. The quantity field in Form Display already has "Allow decimal quantities" unchecked. A bug maybe?

Comment: It doesn't seem likely. There is a test case for this, so it would have failed if it was a bug. But regardless, I tested plain Drupal installation with the exact same versions and it worked as expected. When the checkbox is checked, the items are increasing with a smaller step (as per the configuration) and when I uncheck it, the step is 1. Please check without any additional modules installed. Also, if there are any custom modules, make sure they are not altering this behavior for some reason. Maybe try a fresh installation, enable only the Commerce and the Commerce Checkout and test again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to:
   Administration >> Commerce >> Configuration >> Default >> Manage Form display
2. Under **Default** tab, set Quantity field to Quantity widget.
3. Under **Add to cart** tab, set Quantity field to Quantity widget.

Save and clear cache.